# Translation of "Und ob"

Tags: translation, idiom, german-to-english

> **Die wahre Landlust**
>
> So früh aufstehen, so hart malochen, sich täglich die Finger schmutzig machen - will man das wirklich? Und ob, sagen vier Jungbauern, die sich ganz bewusst für diesen Beruf entschieden haben. Wir haben sie auf ihren Höfen besucht.

Here's my attempt of translating.

> **The true country pleasure**
>
> Getting up so early, working so hard, making one's finger dirty every day - is that really what one wants? And, say four young farmers, whether they have consciously chose this profession. We visited them at their farms.

Is my interpretation of the sentence

> Und ob, sagen vier Jungbauern, die sich ganz bewusst für diesen Beruf entschieden haben.

correct? That is, it is a question whether the farmers consciously chose the profession (and not an assertion that they did consciously choose the profession.)

(Other suggestions on translation are welcome.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your interpretation is not correct. The main problem is that **"Und ob!"** is a fixed idiom that means **"You bet!"**
So the structure of the passage in question is:

> Will man das wirklich? - "Und ob!", sagen vier Jungbauern.
>
> *Do you really want that? - "You bet!" four junior farmers say.*

What follows (*... die sich ... entschieden haben.*) is just a normal relative clause.